# Firebase Analytics Error 21 when logging a firebase e-commerce event in Capital letter instead of lower case

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-analytics

We are trying to send e-commerce events such as SELECT_ITEM event to firebase.
However we get an error 21 on the firebase console saying that the Event does not support array parameters on the "items" parameter that e-commerce events should contain.
We have the same behavior for VIEW_ITEM and VIEW_ITEM_LIS and all the other e-commerce events having an "items" arrays.

We send the event with a custom event name in capital letters and we are not currently using the SDK dedicated constants. Hence, our custom events do not use lower case name such as "item_view" event in the firebase SDK. For instance we log the event with `logEvent("ITEM_VIEW", event)`

Here is an example of the event sent over to Firebase:

```json
event: { 
  screenName: 'option_detail',
  category: 'categorie1',
  sub_category: 'achat_options',
  currency: 'EUR',
  value: 5,
  items: [ 
            { item_id: 'id1',
              item_name: 'option1',
              item_category: 'options',
              item_variant: '',
              item_brand: '',
              price: 5 
            } 
         ],
  platform: 'android' 
}
```

I guess the question sum up to "Does firebase e-commerce events can have custom names with capital letter or should they use the default lower case convention".

Also the second sum up question is "Does firebase custom events can have arrays parameters?".

PS in our app we use the invertase React Native wrapper for the firebase SDK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote directly to the firebase support and received an answer.
It seems indeed that the "items" array parameter is reserved for e-commerce events only and that those are recognized as such only if the event name is in the lowercase naming they provided.